# Magento 2 - class does not exist on setup:di:compile

Tags: php, magento, namespaces, magento2

I have some problem with Magento 2. I've made my own module, it looks to work fine, but when I have my module installed and make `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` there is this error:

> [ReflectionException] Class \MyInstaller does not exist

It is thrown by `setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/PhpScanner.php`

MyInstaller class exists, however I changed path to the class file. Originally, there was path `/my-libraries/MyInstaller.php`, but when I tested it locally, I had error as above:

> [ReflectionException] Class \MyInstaller does not exist

When I changed folder name to mylibraries, on localhost it works fine. However, when I install module on external server, I have `ReflectionException`. It doesn't show when I change folder name to the original one - "my-libraries". As I observed, Magento still calls to the an old path. However, I tried to run new instance of Magento 2 and I still get this error.

I tried to clear cache by:

```
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
```

I tried to delete `/var` folder too. After enable my module, I make:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Could you tell me, how can I force Magento to use new path to the file? Or should I change some cache settings on my server?

I add, there is no namespace in MyInstaller class because I use the same file in another modules. But, I think they are not necessary if on localhost there is no error.

There is MyInstaller class code:

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('MyInstaller', false)) {
class MyInstaller implements MyInterface
{
    private $translations;
    private $sliderEnabled = true;
    private $pages = array();

    public function __construct($sliderEnabled = true, array $translations = array())
    {
        $this->sliderEnabled = $sliderEnabled;
        $this->setTranslations($translations);
    }

    public function setTranslations(array $translations = array())
    {
        $this->translations = $translations;

    }

    public function addPages(array $pages = array())
    {
        $this->pages = array_values($pages);
    }

    public function renderInstallerSteps()
    {
        if (!$this->sliderEnabled || empty($this->pages) || !is_array($this->pages)) {
            return '';
        }

        $requirements = $this->checkRequirements();
        $params = array(
            'requirements' => $requirements,
            'translations' => $this->translations
        );
        $maxSteps = 0;
        $data = array(
            'steps' => array()
        );
        foreach ($this->pages as $page) {
            $page = (int)$page;
            if ($page > 0) {
                $step = $this->loadStep($page, $params);
                $data['steps'][$page] = $step;
                $maxSteps++;
            }
        }

        if ($maxSteps === 0) {
            return '';
        }
        $data['maxSteps'] = $maxSteps;

        return $this->loadTemplate('installer', $data);
    }

    private function loadStep($number, $params = null)
    {
        $step = $this->loadTemplate('step' . $number, $params);
        $step = $this->removeNewLines($step);
        return $step;
    }

    private function removeNewLines($string)
    {
        return trim(str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $string));
    }

    private function loadTemplate($view, $data = null)
    {
        extract(array("content" => $data));
        ob_start();
        $viewFile = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'theme' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "$view.tpl.php";

        if (file_exists($viewFile)) {
            include $viewFile;
        } else {
            throw new Exception('View not exist in ' . get_class($this));
        }
        $content = ob_get_clean();
        return $content;
    }

    private function checkRequirements()
    {
        $data = array(
            'php' => array(
                'test' => (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.2.0') > 0),
                'label' => $this->translations['php_version']
            ),
            'curl' => array(
                'test' => function_exists('curl_version'),
                'label' => $this->translations['curl_enabled']
            ),
            'soap' => array(
                'test' => class_exists('SoapClient'),
                'label' => $this->translations['soap_enabled']
            )
        );
        return $data;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry, if description is chaotical, this is my first post here.

Comment: you need to use namespaces in Magento 2... that's probably why it isn't being found

Comment: I thought about that, but there is no error when I change folder name to the original one - 'my-libraries' without namespaces. Moreover, locally it works. Could it be something else?

Comment: is your local environment different from your production/dev? e.g. windows on local, linux on dev? if so, windows is case-insensitive so This is the same as this whereas on linux, that would be two different files

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. It was a problem with case sensitive, I changed folder name into MyLibraries and it works fine on local and production.

Comment: Updated my answer for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Magento2 depends on namespaces to separate and locate modules and classes.

ALL FILES NEED A DECLARED NAMESPACE like so:

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\MyModule\Setup;

    class MyInstaller implements ... {}
```

EDIT - AFTER SEEING COMMENT

Also check for case-sensitivity - UNIX systems treat This and this as two separate files whereas Windows will see it as one.